# which column of sql table is equal to a variable

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlite

i want to find the value of 'vazn' (one column of sql table) where 'id' column is equal to f1.
the table name is "billse"
"vazn" & "id1" are the columns of this table...
"f1" is a variable

f1 is a variable as following:

```
f1=int(enter3.get())
```

enter3 is an entry.

i entered the variable in enter3 that is equal to one of the existing 'id's in the sql table('bills')
this is my code:

```
self.cur.execute("SELECT vazn FROM billse WHERE id1='f1'")
            vaznp = self.cur.fetchall()
            print(vaznp)
```

i get 'null' when it prints vaznp
Why?

Comment: Which database is it, SQL Server or sqlite? Beware that syntax is specific for each database, use the appropriate tags

Comment: is f1 a variable containing a value, or is it a value ? Its not clear to me from your explanation

Comment: To me, you are looking for `id1` column to be `=` to the text `f1`. Is this correct? The single quotes around `f1` denote it as text.

Comment: I'm not sure if I've understood properly, but what about `cur.execute("SELECT vazn FROM billse WHERE id1=?", (f1,))`?

Answer (score 1):

Use a prepared statement:

```
self.cur.execute("SELECT vazn FROM billse WHERE id1=?", f1)
vaznp = self.cur.fetchall()
print(vaznp)
```

Your current query is literally being interpreted as this:

```
SELECT vazn FROM billse WHERE id1='f1'
```

In other words, you are comparing the `id1` column against the string `'f1'`, not against the value contained in that variable.  Prepared statements also free you from the worry of dealing with properly escaping strings in your queries.

Comment: ok.my problem was solved...but i have a new problem..please help again...i want to add **vazne** into another table(it maeans **vazne** will becomes one of the the second table columns )...when i print **vazne** , it returns correct value  but as this format : [(360,)]...so when i add it into the second table, i get the following error

Comment: @feri Please open a new question.